# Pushing second query result as an associative array into the existing fetched data from fetch_assoc

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to merge two SQL query result while the first query always will return a single row and the second query may return 0 to many rows. I loaded the first query result to an array in PHP like

```
$data = [];
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $data=$row;
}
```

and tried to append the result of second query (remember this time can be many rows) like

```
while($rowtwo = $resulttwo->fetch_assoc()) {
  array_push($data, array('per' => $row['per'],
'duration' => $row['duration']));
}
```

and the output with `print_r()` looks like

```
Array
(
    [term] => 0
    [available] => 1
    [0] => Array
        (
            [per] => 2019-09-04
            [duration] => 14
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [per] => 2019-09-04
            [duration] => 15
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [per] => 2019-09-04
            [duration] => 15-30
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [per] => 2019-09-04
            [duration] => 16
        )
)
```

But I need to have the second query stored as an array inside the array like

```
Array
(
    [term] => 0
    [available] => 1
    [newarray] = [
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [per] => 2019-09-04
                    [duration] => 14
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [per] => 2019-09-04
                    [duration] => 15
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [per] => 2019-09-04
                    [duration] => 15-30
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [per] => 2019-09-04
                    [duration] => 16
        )
        ]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

After your first query and before the second, add a `newentry` element to your `$data` array. Then push values into that instead of `$data`:

```
$data = [];
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $data = $row;
}
// ...
$data['newentry'] = array();
while($rowtwo = $resulttwo->fetch_assoc()) {
  array_push($data['newentry'], array('per' => $rowtwo['per'],
                                      'duration' => $rowtwo['duration']));
}
```

Note you have `$row` in your second loop. I've corrected that to `$rowtwo` in this code.